# The Angular boilerplate does not produce an environment folder

Tags: angular

I am just starting with Angular and I am following along with a tutorial.  I am sure I am doing the commands as instructed. With a simple command line argument, an entire project is built with the default files and folders that the developer is supposed to work off of.  But my code is missing an **Environments** folder that contains a couple of **.ts** files.  Either the instructor skipped a step in the demonstration or something else is going on.

I took a screen shot of my folder contents adding in the missing part for clarification.  If needed, I will post it here.

Answer (score -1):

Use this best provision provided by Angular to create new enviornments swiftly.

```
ng generate environments
```

It will create 3 environments as follow:

[Environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8x4r.png)

They will have this boiler plate in them:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

To manually create environments, follow these steps:

- Create environments directory
- Create your custom environments like the below

  - environment.ts
  - environment.prod.ts
  - environment.staging.ts etc.

```
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      },
    ]
  },
  "dev": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
      },
    ]
  },
```